# Get request header in JSP Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I set the header in the action class. The code are as follow:

```
public String doMyAction() {

    response.setHeader("abc","cba");
    response.addHeader("abcdefg","1234567890");

    return "target_page";

}
```

At my target_page.jsp, I tried to display the header, but the value is null.

```
<%= request.getHeader("abc") %>           <-- Null
<%= request.getHeader("abcdefg") %>       <-- Null
<%= response.containsHeader("abc") %>     <-- True
<s:property value="%{#request.abc}" />    <-- Empty
<s:text name="%{request.abc}" />          <-- Empty
<s:text name="%{#header.abc}" />          <-- Empty
<s:text name="%{#header['abc']}" />       <-- Empty
```

And in the developer tools, there are my headers.

[image]

In my struts-config.xml,

```
<action name="target_name" class="com.my.Class">
    <result name="target_page">/my/jsp/target_page.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Why I can't get the request header that set in my action class?

EDIT:

How can I get the request header that set in the action class?

Answer (score 2):

The response headers and the request headers are different sets of headers.

You can only set response headers in your server-side code.
Request headers are set by the browser.

If you want to pass data from action class to JSP, you could use request *attributes*.

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the value by setting it as attribute, or using getter method to return the value. But is there any way to get the value from the response header?